# Почему не создается каталог в Linux?

Tags: linux

Пытаюсь установить библиотеки glibc, и для этого мне сначала надо создать каталог:
mkdir /usr/src/glibc-build, но команда mkdir выдает ошибку что невозможно создать каталог - отказ в доступе. В чем проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: права? /usr, /usr/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# mkdir /usr/src/glibc-build
```

В Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/src/glibc-build
```

Answer (score 0):

Так он же вам пишет, что отказано в доступе. Значит, прав не хватает. Значит, нужно из под рута или с помощю sudo сделать то, что вы хотите.